# Frequency distribution graph

Tags: python, r, frequency-distribution

Is there a way to draw a frequency distribution graph in python or R?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In R, using histograms, which show frequency on y axis vs some categorization on x-axis as in your example.

- `hist()` function at the very least help you plot one vector (a set of values). `?hist` for brief documentation, also search this site
- how to plot two vectors side by side, similar to your posted example, an example is at http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_distributions_(ggplot2)/ , scroll down to `Histogram and density plots with multiple groups`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually the numbers I have are not gradually distributed. So I want to use somewhat arbitrary intervals (e.g., 0-1, 1-2, 2-3) to get the frequency for each interval. Would hist() work for this?